# Applescript to set transition timers

Tags: applescript, keynote

I recently switched from PowerPoint to Keynote. I have ~50 presentations and together they add up to more than 5000 slides.
Each slide has embedded audios it can be anywhere from 3 seconds to 30 seconds long. In PowerPoint I wrote a Macro to insert audios to slide and add transition timer same as audio length.

With Keynote I can read / play the presentations well, audio plays well but all the transition timers are disabled.

If I click auto transition then it sets every slide transition timer to 0.5s which I can change but going through all the slides and setting the timer manually is such a mundane task that I have not inclination of doing it.

Can the transition times for a presentation can be interested with automator  or can it be imported from a CSV sort of file. The way I did this in Powerpoint was I created a static array with all slides timer I wanted, later looped through each slide and set the timer. can similar thing can be done in Keynote with applescript

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this works, but I'm not totally familiar with the nuances of these settings:

```
tell application "Keynote"
    set ss to slides of document 1
    set c to count of ss
    set n to 1
    repeat until n > c
        set transition properties of item n of ss to {transition delay:0.5, automatic transition:false, transition effect:no transition effect, transition duration:0.5}
        set n to n + 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

---

Here is the solution - it worked beautifully. I did not find any glitches.

```
tell application "Keynote"
    set ss to slides of document 1
    set c to count of ss
    set timerlist to {5, 4, 3, 9, 6}
    set n to 1

    repeat until n > c
        set timer to item n of timerlist
        set transition properties of item n of ss to {transition delay:timer, automatic transition:true, transition effect:no transition effect, transition duration:0.5}
        set n to n + 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I am getting this error "error "Keynote got an error: Can’t get document 1. Invalid index." number -1719 from document 1" - Is there a way to give the path in the script itself and open desired file

Comment: Yes, you can either open the project and run this script (keep backups, please), or have the script open the file first. You're basically asking me to do the code for you, which is not really how this site is supposed to work. Try putting this at beginning: `tell app "Keynote" to open (choose file)` or get the file path by doing choose file and put the path returned in between parentheses.

Comment: No I am not asking you to do the coding for me - like I said in my post I was a powerpoint VB guy who has no background in applescript. I am learning but wanted to know some more. I will try to create a code and if I get hung up on then I will post here for some help. Thanks

Comment: No prob. Feel free. I hope you find a solution.

Comment: thanks a  lot for your help, I can not tell me how many hours it saved for me. Thank you